# Manual Action necessary for the API to return Entities ?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow’s API to feed intents and their respective entities. We’re doing this as a team so modifications are made on a pretty regular basis.
In the meantime, we select some utterances for which we know the desired classification, and we check via Dialogflow’s API (the /query endpoint) that the actual result meets the expectations.

For intents, the results are great. We always get an intent back from the API, and all is well.
As far as entities are concerned however, we have a peculiar behavior :

- when we update the training (we add utterances, intents and entities) via the API without any manual action on the DialogFlow console, **we don’t get any entities in the JSON response to /query**
- when we do the same thing, but we manually click on the « Save » button of all the intents,** we get entities in the JSON response** after the « Agent Started Training » flash message disappears.

Does this mean that there is **always at least one manual action required for the training to actually be fully done** and for entities to be returned in JSON response to the /query endpoint ? Is there a way for us to launch that training via API and prevent the manual save of the 100+ intents we have for our Agent ?

Thanks for any help you can provide !

Best regards